# Добавление нового блока, удаление последнего

Tags: ajax, html, javascript, php

Есть div для контента, который содержит первую фразу приветствия.

```
<HTML>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="product-thumbnail">
    <p class="pult-name">Летопись</p>
    <div id="let_info">

    <div id="data"> $date </div>
  <p>$leader_name, народ встречает вас с вкуснейшим хле... С солью. Да, с солью встречает.</p>

</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

JS с помощью ajax посылает запрос на сервер, получает ответ в виде нового сообщения, которое в последствии, благодаря $("#let_info").prepend(letopis_msg); добавится в летопись (div блок с id="let_info")
где letopis_msg - ответ сервера.

к примеру ответ может быть таким

```
<div id=\"1\">
  <div id=\"data\"> $date </div>
  <p>$leader_name, народ доволен, будьте довольны и вы.</p>
</div>
```

Проблемы следующие.

1) добавленые элементы съезжают, и всегда по разному.

[image]

2) Как сделать так чтобы старая запись, когда их ко-во достигнет 10, удалялась?

Comment: @lordvakar, id элемента должен быть уникальным на странице и не может начинаться с цифры. Съезжает скорее всего из-за флоатов в css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) добавленые элементы съезжают, и всегда по разному.

Съезжает из-за флоата, варианты решения:

1. задать минимальную высоту блоку с сообщением
2. использовать clearfix

> 2) Как сделать так чтобы старая запись, когда их ко-во достигнет 10, удалялась?

при помощи jquery считать количество сообщений `$("div.mess").length` и удалять последний как только количество будет равно 10